# Why do Mac OS X python versus CentOS Linux python have different interpretations of \U escapes in strings?

Tags: python, macos, unicode, centos

Two python interpreter sessions. The first is from python on CentOS. The second is from the built-in python on Mac OS X 10.7. Why does the second session create strings of length two from the \U escape sequence, and subsequently error out?

```
$ python
Python 2.6.6 (r266:84292, Dec  7 2011, 20:48:22) 
[GCC 4.4.6 20110731 (Red Hat 4.4.6-3)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> u'\U00000020'
u' '
>>> u'\U00000065'
u'e'
>>> u'\U0000FFFF'
u'\uffff'
>>> u'\U00010000'
u'\U00010000'
>>> len(u'\U00010000')
1
>>> ord(u'\U00010000')
65536
```

---

```
$ python
Python 2.6.7 (r267:88850, Jul 31 2011, 19:30:54) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2335.15.00)] on darwin
>>> u'\U00000020'
u' '
>>> u'\U00000065'
u'e'
>>> u'\U0000FFFF'
u'\uffff'
>>> u'\U00010000'
u'\U00010000'
>>> len(u'\U00010000')
2
>>> ord(u'\U00010000')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: ord() expected a character, but string of length 2 found
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not at all sure about this, but it may be that your Mac OS X system uses a "narrow build" of python that represents unicode with only 16 bits for internal encoding of unicode, and represents the unicode code points above 2**16 as a character pair (which would explain `len(u'\U00010000') == 2`.

Try `unichr(0x10000)` on OS X and see if you get an error referring to narrow builds. See also [What encoding do normal python strings use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3547534/what-encoding-do-normal-python-strings-use), in particular IVH's answer.

It's possible to recompile python to use a wide build even if the default python on your system uses a narrow build.

Comment: Good catch. That's probably it. See this article too: http://wordaligned.org/articles/narrow-python

Comment: This is the right answer. I get the error about "narrow Python build" and sys.maxunicode returns 65535 on Mac OS X.

Comment: @user802500: I might be misunderstanding, but isn't it Mac OS that has the narrow build in this case?

Comment: You're right. I'd flipped which OS was doing what when I was answering the post. It's edited now.