# How i can generate a keyboard event(PRESS F5) using python?

Tags: python, events, keyboard

I tried this way but it is not working as expected,

```
import win32api
import win32con
import time
time.sleep(3)
win32api.keybd_event(win32con.VK_F5,0x74,0,0)
```

Comment: Refer [**here**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3547551/5756174). It suggests [wxPython KeyEvent](http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.KeyEvent-class.html)