# How to convert Russian character to integer

Tags: python, character-encoding, ord

I use python to convert Russian character to int style.
I know the Russian character int value is less than 256.
but I get the value above 1000. how to get correct value?
My projcet encoding is ISO-8859-5.
code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: iso-8859-5 -*-
rus_str = "бвгдеёжзийя"

for i in rus_str:
    print(ord(i))
```

Result:

```
1073
1074
1075
1076
1077
1105
1078
1079
1080
1081
1103
```

Comment: Python uses Unicode, not ISO-8859-5, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3547534/what-encoding-do-normal-python-strings-use

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you need the ISO-8859-5 value, or will Unicode do?

Comment: if I use Unicode there will be an build error.  if I use Unicode there will be an build error.D:\Python\Russian2Octal\env\Scripts\python.exe D:/Python/Russian2Octal/env/Russian2Octal.py
  File "D:/Python/Russian2Octal/env/Russian2Octal.py", line 3
SyntaxError: Non-UTF-8 code starting with '\xd1' in file D:/Python/Russian2Octal/env/Russian2Octal.py on line 3, but no encoding declared; see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details

Process finished with exit code 1

Answer (score 0):

Actually, ord() function return string representation in Unicode, where all Russian characters have number in range from 1040 to 1103. There is also number 1025 for "ё" and "Ё".
For your task, you can encode string and then get ASCII code:

```
rus_str = "бвгдеёжзийя".encode('ISO-8859-5')

for i in rus_str:
    print(i)
```

Result:

```
209
210
211
212
213
241
214
215
216
217
239
```

Comment: thank you . get it! ord() function return string representation in Unicode, where all Russian characters have number in range from 1040 to 1103